# sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer(): using SimpleImputer() and OneHotEncoder() in one step on one dataframe column

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, one-hot-encoding, imputation

I have a dataframe containing a column with categorical variables, which also includes NaNs.

```
  Category
1 A
2 A
3 Na
4 B
```

I'd like to to use `sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer()` to prepare the df in a clean way. I tried to impute nan values and OneHotEncode the column with the following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer

transformer= make_column_transformer(
    (SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent'), ['Category']),
    (OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), ['Category'])
)
```

Running the transformer on my training data raises

> ValueError: Input contains NaN

```
transformer.fit(X_train)
X_train_trans = transformer.transform(X_train)
```

The desired output would be something like that:

```
  A B
1 1 0
2 1 0
3 1 0
4 0 1
```

That raises two questions:

1. Does the transformer computes both the `SimpleImputer` and the `OneHotEncoder` in parallel on the original data or in the order I introduced them in the transformer?
2. How can I change my code so that the `OneHotEncoder` gets the imputed values as an input? I know that I can solve it outside of the transformer with pandas in two different steps, but I'd like to have the code in a clean pipeline format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [sklearn Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html?highlight=pipeline#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline) to *sequentially apply a list of transforms*:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

s = pd.DataFrame(data={'Category': ['A', 'A', np.nan, 'B']})

category_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False))
    ]
)

transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('category', category_pipeline , ['Category'])
    ],
)

transformer.fit_transform(s)
array([[1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]])
```